# svn update: can I iterate the results?

Tags: svn, windows-scripting

I'm using svn in a script (Windows scripting .cmd file).

Currently it checks out all files to a folder, then iterates that folder adding all the files to a master file as part of a build process. Something like:

```
svn checkout --username %username% %SVNURL% %workingfolder%
FOR %%i IN (%workingfolder%\*.*) DO TYPE %%i >> %DESTFILE%
```

What I would like to do for builds after the inital build is produce a "change" file, that only has the files included which have changed since the last build.

I can use the svn **update** command instead of checkout, and this gives me a list of files being updated. [svn update Reference (svnbook.red-bean.com)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html)

What I would like to do is iterate this list of results from the svn update, find these files within the working folder and copy them to a change file.

Comment: I'm confused; do you need to do this via `svn update` or checkout? If it's update, as you say, you can get the list and do what you want with it (I don't know exactly how in DOS, but ...) Is that what you're asking: How to do it in DOS? Or how to get the list, in general?

Comment: Yes I guess how to do in DOS was my question, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find updated files pretty easily:

```
svn up | findstr /r /c:"^U"
```

You can iterate over the output of that with the `for` command:

```
for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%x in ('svn up ^| findstr /r /c:"^U"') do copy "%%x" change
```

Comment: Thanks, have read up on all commands in use there, currently trying to get this to work:
    for /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%x in ('%SVNExecutable%svn up --username user.name  %SVNURL% %procsfolder% ^| findstr /r /c:"^U"') do ECHO %%x
Problem is that %SVNExecutable% includes a space in the path (Program Files) and so this errors ('C:\Program' is not recognized ....). Tried comments around %SVNExecutable% but that doesn't work...any way I think your answer is correct, so thanks, any further help gratefully received: how can I escape the space?

Comment: Quotes around the argument to `copy` should suffice. Sorry, I forgot them. Can't test here right now with file names with spaces, though, but the `for` statement should work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for answering my own question, this is also only a partial answer but it's where I'm at currently.

Firstly, the problem with the spaces is not just with the file path in %SVNExecutable%, the problem is with spaces in the command at all.

The way to solve this problem (works on windows XP) is to use the **usebackq** switch, and use back quotes **`** instead of normal quotes. Using this, I have managed to get the svn update command to work:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %%x in (`%SVNExecutable%svn up --username %username% %SVNURL% %workfolder%`) do ECHO "%%x"
```

This updated the test file, and from an initial update result of:

```
U    full\path\to\file\file.sql
Updated to revision 36793.
Summary of conflicts:
Skipped paths: 1
```

This produces a result of:

```
"full\path\to\file\file.sql"
"to"
"of"
"paths:"
```

The last remaining piece of the puzzle that I can't get to work is the findstr with regex. When I add this back in and try this:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims= " %%x in (`%SVNExecutable%svn up --username %username% %SVNURL% %workfolder% ^| findstr /r /c:"^U"`) do ECHO "%%x"
```

I get this error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Was in 2 minds whether to start this as a new question now I've marked this one as answered...anyway, all help gratefully received